# Drawing tubes with a While loop

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to make a plot with many objects in it using a `While` loop.

Something like the following:

```
Graphics3D[
  While[ϕforwhile < Pi/3, 
    {Lighter[Blue, .1], 
       {Tube[
          Table[
            u*{Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[ϕforwhile], Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[ϕforwhile], Cos[Pi/2]},
            {u, 0, 1, 1/10}],
          .005]}};
    ϕforwhile = ϕforwhile + Pi/12;]]
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: The important thing to realize here is that `Tube` does not draw a tube.  It represents a tube.  In other words, Mathematica's graphics language is declarative. Thus what you need to do it not evaluate those `Tube`s one by one but collect them in a list, and wrap that list with `Graphics3D`.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing here is that `While` produces no output.  For that you will need to use something like the `Sow` `Reap` suggested by @rasher.

I would recommend using `Table` here which produces output.

```
Graphics3D[{Lighter[Blue, .1], 
  Table[{Tube[
     Table[u*{Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[\[Phi]forwhile], 
        Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[\[Phi]forwhile], Cos[Pi/2]}, {u, 0, 1, 
       1/10}], .005]}, {\[Phi]forwhile, 0, Pi/3, Pi/12}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ϕforwhile = 0;

res = Reap[
    While[ϕforwhile < Pi/3, 
     Sow[{Lighter[
        Blue, .1], {Tube[
         Table[u*{Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[ϕforwhile], 
            Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[ϕforwhile], Cos[Pi/2]}, {u, 0, 1, 
           1/10}], .005]}}]; ϕforwhile = ϕforwhile + 
       Pi/12;]][[2]];

Graphics3D[res]
```

[image]

The `While` on its own will not give you what you're looking for - you need to use things like `Sow` and `Reap`, or use `Table`, etc. `While` is simply a looping construct, any results are from side-effects and explicit generation like above. Also, note the initialization of the tested symbol. Without that, your initial test fails (try doing such a test on an uninitialized symbol interactively, observe the result...)